# Difference between `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` and `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`?

Tags: hadoop, memory-management, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

What is difference between `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` and `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`?

I see both of these in `yarn-site.xml` and I see the explanations [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml).

`yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` is given the following definition: *The maximum allocation for every container request at the RM, in MBs. Memory requests higher than this will throw a InvalidResourceRequestException.*  Does this mean memory requests ONLY on the resourcemanager are limited by this value?

And `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` is given definition of *Amount of physical memory, in MB, that can be allocated for containers.*  Does this mean the total amount for all containers across the entire cluster, summed together?

HOwever, I still cannot discern between these.  Those explanations make me think that they are the same.

Even more confusing, their default values are exactly the same: 8192 mb.  How do I tell difference between these?  Thank you.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Consider in a scenario where you are setting up a cluster where each machine having 48 GB of RAM. Some of this RAM should be reserved for Operating System and other installed applications.

---

***yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb:***

Amount of physical memory, in MB, that can be allocated for containers. It means the amount of memory YARN can utilize **on this node** and therefore this property 
should be **lower than the total memory of that machine**.

```
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>40960</value> <!-- 40 GB -->
```

---

The *next step is to provide YARN guidance on how to break up the total resources available into Containers*. You do this by specifying the minimum unit of RAM to allocate for a Container.

In `yarn-site.xml`

```
<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name> <!-- RAM-per-container ->
 <value>2048</value>
```

***yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb:***

It defines the maximum **memory allocation available for a container** in MB

it means RM can only allocate memory to containers in increments of `"yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb"` and not exceed `"yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb"` and It should not be more then total allocated memory of the Node.

In `yarn-site.xml`

```
<name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name> <!-Max RAM-per-container->
 <value>8192</value>
```

For MapReduce applications, **YARN processes each map or reduce task in a container and on a single machine there can be  number of containers**.
We want to allow for a maximum of 20 containers on each node, and thus need (40 GB total RAM) / (20 # of containers) = 2 GB minimum per container controlled by  property `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb`

Again we want to restrict maximum memory utilization for a container controlled by property `"yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb"`

For example, if one job is asking for 2049 MB memory per map container(`mapreduce.map.memory.mb=2048 set in mapred-site.xml`), RM will give it one 4096 MB(`2*yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb`) container.

If you have a huge MR job which asks for a 9999 MB map container, the job will be killed with the error message.

Comment: `<!-- RAM-per-container -> <value>2048</value>` -- I don't think that is necessarily "RAM per container" because I think `spark.executor.memory` is how much memory is set per container/executor.

Comment: HOw do these settings interact with spark?   I think spark will override these settings, correct?  Especially if one is using a capacity scheduler....

Comment: Last thing - Why do they both default to the same value (`8192 mb`)?  That would mean the default is only one container per machine?!?!  that doesn't sound correct.

Comment: yes, all this setting are for map reduce applications, and can be overwritten by user defined setting in application.

Comment: Spark has there one configuration setting and it will be overwritten by spark applications.

Comment: Default setting are just for knowledge not a cluster recommendation. HDP or Cloudera provides utility to recalculate these setting for deployment.

Comment: please visit this link for more information about memory calculation :https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.3/bk_installing_manually_book/content/determine-hdp-memory-config.html

Comment: @SandeepSingh do we have to set/alter `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` on each cluster node?

Comment: Yes, we should put updated yarn-site.xml on all nodes in the cluster.

Comment: does this setting only apply to mapreduce or spark as well?