# How to control YARN container allocation increment properly?

Tags: hadoop, memory-management, resources, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

Say I want to increase the default value for YARN container from 1024 MB to 1200MB and make all YARN containers memory be a multiple of 1200MB (2400MB, 3600MB, so on).

I can control max size and min size of the container using YARN parameters `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` and `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` as it is stated in **Hadoop The Definitive Guide**.
I believed that allocation increments are same as `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43827548/9145106)), until recently came across [mentions of `yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb` parameter](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/quot-yarn-scheduler-increment-allocation-mb-quot-when-and/td-p/44970):

> Request a container 1200MB/1vcore: minimum size is 1GB, increment is 500MB -> a container of 1.5GB (rounded up to the next increment, the minimum is used as a base)

I did not find any mentions nor default values of this parameter in [yarn-defaults.xml for Hadoop 3.1.1](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) not to mention the older versions.

**So my questions are**: do I need to set `yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb` explicitly to 1200MB in `yarn-site.xml` and what is the default value for this property?

Just to add more details, my Hadoop version is 2.6.0-cdh5.9.2 (Cloudera distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Cloudera docs](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/cm_mc_yarn_service.html#id_qv5_4ts_3q), the default is 512 MB.

Yes, you'll need to set `yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb` to 1200MB in order to have container size incremented in multiples of that.

Comment: @GoodDok Just out of curiosity - why do you need it?

Comment: we've got relation vmemory/vcores ~ 1200MB in our cluster, so the container size was set to that value some time ago + all of the sudden `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` was set to the same value.  
Nevertheless, now I investigate how to get away from this configuration without breaking the existing logic.

Comment: I see. Just wanted to warn that if you're running a lot of Spark apps with default configs (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/configuration.html), AMs will be requesting  containers with 1.384 GB (`spark.executor.memory`=1g and `spark.executor.memoryOverhead`=384m by default) but YARN with your new setting will promote contianer size to 2400m, so you will end up with less executor containers.