# AWS EMR YARN does not allocate all requested executors

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

**The situation:**
1x Primary node:

- 4-cores
- 8GiB memory

2x core nodes:

- 16-cores
  -64GiB memory

I tried to request 6 executors, each running 5 cores, so that my application would utilise 30 cores total. The idea here was to have each core node allocate 3 executors, each using 5 cores. That means each node uses 15 cores for the executor, and 1 core for the YARN manager.

Within the scala application, my spark settings are:

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .appName("Lab2")
  .config("spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles", "true")
  .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
  .config("spark.kyro.registrationRequired", "false")
  .getOrCreate()
```

For the spark-submit, I use the following submit settings:

```
--num-executors 6
--executor-cores 5
--executor-memory 18g
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false
```

However, my Hadoop YARN logs tell me that YarnAllocator **requested 6 executors**, but it only receives 4 executors. Looking from the IP address, it seems that each node only allocates two executors, instead of 3 executors.

I also tried setting:

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator
```

Nothing seems to work sadly.

Do you maybe have any suggestions on why I can only use 20 cores, from the available 32 cores on the Core nodes?

Kind regards.

I tried many YARN configs and Spark-submit configs. None of the above worked. It does create 4 executors, but not more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the amount of executor's memory so the total amount of memory used per node is within YARN's limits for that EC2 instance type.

AWS EMR specifies its own [default configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html) for YARN, and it limits the amount of memory applications can use. The defaults are different for different EC2 instance types. For example, for d3en.4xlarge, that similarly to your instance type has 16 CPUs and 64 GiB of RAM, yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb is 54272 MiB or 53 GiB, not 64 GiB, and for three executors per node maximum memory would be 53/3 = 17.6 GiB that is less than 18 GiB that you specified.

Please see discussion [Difference between yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb and yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826703/difference-between-yarn-scheduler-maximum-allocation-mb-and-yarn-nodemanager) for more information.